# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 2 is null

Tags: android, sqlite, illegalargumentexception

Just wondering that for few Android devices we are getting below mentioned exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 2 is 
null 
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SourceFile:237) 
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict 
(SourceFile:1794) 
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.update(SourceFile:1730) 
at com.sample.android.SQDBHelper.onUpgrade(SourceFile:276) 
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase 
(SourceFile:123) 
at com.sample.android.SQDBController.read(SourceFile:431) 
at com.sample.android.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:42)  
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate 
(Instrumentation.java:1104) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
```

sample Code

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

contentValues.put("COL_VALUE1", value1);
contentValues.put("COL_VALUE2", value2);
contentValues.put("COL_VALUE3", value3);
contentValues.put("COL_VALUE4", value4);
contentValues.put("COL_VALUE5", value5);

database.insert(DATA_TABLE, null, contentValues);
```

This is true that bound value2 is coming as a null value and we can handle it. However Wondering why in most of the devices we didn't observe above exception.

Comment: not without seeing your code and the complete LogCat

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your application activity get kill by the Android OS, and when it reconstruct from the savedInstanceState, it is not in the right state.

This can be happened when user use home button to switch to another app (not back until exit your app). While your app is in the background, The os destroys your app activity. 
Once user switch back to your app then activity is recreated from savedInstanceState.

To simulate this scenario, you can use the Settings > Developer Options > check the option "Don't keep activities", and test your app at the screen with this error occurred using home button, then resume your app and see you can reproduce it or not.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. We tried the same but not able to reproduce the scenario where we can get above exception. These exception we got from Google play.

Comment: somewhere our issue is similar to [https://github.com/AnySoftKeyboard/AnySoftKeyboard/issues/126]